# Visual PHP GUI IDE

Tags: php, user-interface, desktop-application

Does anybody know of a reliable, well-made tool for creating standalone desktop applications complete with GUI, using just PHP, or primarily PHP?  I enjoy the R.A.D. and many other aspects of PHP and would like to use it for some non server/client projects.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you really should not be using PHP for this. Why do you think there aren't any tools for this? It will be a much less painful experience to use C# if you're on windows, or Python or Ruby if you still want to use a similar scripting language.

Comment: C# is an absolute abortion.  Python has a completely unfamiliar syntax coming from most other languages, esp C++, and I don't know anything about Ruby.  I believe that the MAIN reason that I "shouldn't" be using PHP for this, is ONLY because it seems no good standard GUI Apparatus exists for desktop applications, and it isn't usually wise to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The Roadsend PHP project, which I plugged in my original answer back in 2010, appears to be a dead project. For what it's worth, you can find the source and a couple of spin-off projects at:

https://github.com/weyrick/roadsend-php

For anyone looking for an answer to this question, my first suggestion would be to look into a modern cross-platform GUI development platform -- personally I like Java + Apache Pivot.

But whether you take my suggestion, or are committed to PHP-GTK, my IDE recommendation's the same: You'll want to try out NetBeans and possibly Eclipse. Both are powerful IDE's well-suited for development on either of the aforementioned platforms.

**Original Answer:**

> Yes!
>
> **Roadsend PHP**
>
> http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler [dead link]
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadsend_PHP [dead link]
>
> *More information from the Roadsend site:*
>
> **Build Stand Alone Applications From Standard PHP Source Code**
>
> Roadsend compiles your PHP project to a single, native binary which
>   does not require an interpreter. Roadsend builds online web
>   applications with FastCGI, offline web applications with an embedded
>   web server (MicroServer), desktop GUI applications with PHP-GTK, and
>   more! Supports Windows, Unix, and Mac OS X.
>
> *NEW: PHP 5 compatible since version 2.9.3*
>
> **Roadsend Studio IDE**
>
> Roadsend Studio helps you manage, build, debug and deploy your PHP
>   projects with the Roadsend Compiler. It automatically deploys a
>   finished project to a directory (included supporting libraries), ready
>   for packaging. It examines your code as you type, has early syntax
>   error recognition, auto method and property completion and auto
>   parameter help. Full syntax highlighting editor, project source file
>   manager, step debugger and compiling and interpreting of projects
>   (including GUI apps) from within the IDE.
>
> **Compile Web Applications**
>
> Compile web applications for both on- and offline use. Online web
>   applications use the standard FastCGI interface for communicating with
>   industry standard web servers such as Apache and Microsoft IIS.
>   Offline web applications use the MicroServer embedded web server,
>   which allows you to run an web application as a stand alone program.
>
> **Compile Desktop GUI Applications** The Roadsend Compiler uses the GTK library for cross platform operability. It supports the Glade user
>   interface builder and is compatible with the PHP-GTK 1 API.
>
> **Debugger**
>
> Roadsend Compiler includes a step debugger which allows you to step
>   line by line through your source. You have the ability to set
>   breakpoints by source file or line number, pause a running program,
>   inspect local variables and inspect the call stack.
>
> *NEW: Step debug web applications!*

Comment: And for the record I have NO connection to the Roadsend project, but I don't feel bad posting what amounts to a marketing spiel, because it's a GPL project and seems fairly well supported. I won't claim that it's great to work with -- I frankly have no idea, as I've downloaded and perused their solution but never actually built anything with it.

Comment: Their GUI Features don't seem to be available under Windows yet. :(

Comment: Brian, I'm glad you posted something. The Roadsend website appears to be a single page with a link to the Git repository, and no description of the project. The Wikipedia page has been deleted. I have to wonder if the GUI features were developed for Windows before the developers ceased working on it. I'd like to know more about it before I dowwnload the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Delphi for PHP](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-for-php) but it appears to be fashioned for web development.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to run on Windows I've actually made applications for paying customers using [miniPHP](http://www.exvision.net/miniphp/) IDE. It's not VisualStudio for sure, but it's usable.

Answer (score 0):

for Windows there is real cool simple but fullready thing: [DevelStudio](http://jkeks.com/archives/9)
Thats Russian, but translation included.
url: http://develstudio.ru/downloads/